# Metrics like response time of an API in spring cloud gateway

Tags: spring, jmx, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using Spring Cloud Gateway and would want to capture the metrics for all API hits. Metrics include response time, error codes, etc. I am using Hoxton.RELEASE version of Spring cloud. 
I tried using /actuator/metrics/gateway.requests as suggested in their documentation but it didn't work. Also , it will be better if these metrics would be available through jmx metrics. I tried using jmx as well and visualized it on jconsole but it wasn't showing the response time ,etc for an API.

Could someone suggest how to do it? We have to use it in production and this is an important factor for us.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue that's really headache. The endpoint is not working:

```
/actuator/metrics/gateway.requests
```

I finally figure out that if you don't have data `(requests, responses)` that endpoint will not work, it will show `error` when you check it with your browser (it's really not preferable and make everyone confuse, like you and me)

I have to make script to curl the gateway in order to generate the requests so then the endpoint can have data to work

Also in the application. properties you have to make sure these configured

```
management.endpoint.gateway.enabled=true # default value

management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=gateway
```

Reference link: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gateway/2.2.0.RC1/reference/html/#actuator-api

Another interesting thing is about the graphical dashboard that Spring supports for Grafana, you can use this json definition from Spring and import it into your Grafana.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gateway/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/gateway-grafana-dashboard.json

The dashboard will look like this:

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gateway/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/images/gateway-grafana-dashboard.jpeg

Reference link:
https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-gateway/2.2.1.RELEASE/reference/html/#the-gateway-metrics-filter

Btw, the above GatewayFilter can work out too but that will add another layer to your filter-chain and it might create little overhead for your gateway, if you have the high load, you need to consider this cause it might downgrade your application

Regarding the JMX, you can reference here Spring official document:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html#actuator.endpoints.exposing

Most of the endpoint supports JMX, including Spring Gateway

Answer (score 1):

After checking  '/actuator/metrics'
Its metrics now is '/actuator/metrics/spring.cloud.gateway.requests'
on "spring-cloud-starter-gateway".

[image: my image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to add metrics in server.management.endpoints.web.exposure.include

```json
server:
  spring:
    cloud:
      gateway:
        metrics:
          enabled: true
          tags:
            path:
              enabled: true
    management:
      endpoints:
        web:
          exposure:
            include: health,metrics
```

Answer (score 0):

#### You can capture the response time of all the API hits to spring cloud gateway by writing a custom filter factory like below:

```
    ResponseFilterFactory extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<ResponseFilterFactory.Config> {

    public ResponseFilterFactory() {
            super(Config.class);
        }

       @Override
public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
return new OrderedGatewayFilter((exchange, chain) -> {
// Pre-processing
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    return chain.filter(exchange)
      .then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
          // Post-processing
             String serviceResponseStatus= exchange.getResponse().getStatusCode().toString();

                if(serviceResponseStatus.startsWith("2")){
                    serviceResponseStatus="Success";
                }
                else{
                    serviceResponseStatus="Failure";
                }
            long execTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
            LOGGER.info("caller={}, serviceName={}, serviceResponseStatus={}, serviceResponseTime(ms)={}", Objects.isNull(caller) ? "default" : caller,
                    serviceName, serviceResponseStatus, execTime);

      }));
},1);
}


        public static class Config {
                private String headerName;

                public String getHeaderName() {
    // add some thing to config if you want to log along with resp time, ex. headers etc
                       return null;
                }
        }
```

#### After this you can add this in your routing config file as a default filter:

```
  cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
      - name: ResponseFilterFactory
```

Comment: Why would you write this yourself when Spring Cloud Gateway already provides logging of request timing out of the box (when configured correctly)?

Comment: may be they added it now, i dont recall or knew there was a way out of box back then, can you share how you can achieve it and log the end to end response time just before response goes back ?

Comment: It's this filter: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/main/docs/src/main/asciidoc/spring-cloud-gateway.adoc#the-gateway-metrics-filter although previously it was documented incorrectly, which wasn't fixed until https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/2273

Comment: this does not log response time in log file/console but you need to invoke actuator end point which was not the actual requirement for us

Comment: Indeed, OP asked for jmx though.